# discord.js Role Manager not showing role

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I wanted to have a check on whether a user has a role or not, with a simple

```
let author = message.author.id
let guild = await client.guilds.fetch("guild")
let member = await guild.members.fetch(author)

member.roles.cache.has("role")
```

However, sometimes it returns `false` even though I just gave that member a role. And it still returns `true` after I remove their role. It'll work again only after I reset the bot.

Is this a bug or do I need to cache the member as a whole again? If so, how would I go about doing this to make it quick?

Comment: I kinda didn't get what you tried to do, but I recommend you using just `message.member` insteaf of `let author = message.author.id; let member = await guild.members.fetch(author)` because it's the same thing, but your code will look better!

Comment: @MegaMix_Craft `message.member` only works inside a guild server, I wanted to process the command in the DM while checking the roles in a specific guild as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a cache issue you're facing...

I've not really developed using discord api however reading their documentation I get the impression that you should be using either:

```
await guild.members.fetch({ user: author/id, force: true });
```

The force flag specifies not to use cache in the query - more [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch). Obviously with disabling cache, you might experience performance degradation.

Additionally, the documentation specifies `message.member` object which might be doing this already for you, saving you a query or two.

Comment: `message.member` only works inside a guild server, I wanted to process the command in the DM while checking the roles in a specific guild as well.

Comment: @Prism It does seem to be a cache issue though with the inconsistent results. I'd give the "force" flag a try in that case.

Comment: Force flag seems to be helping the issue, could not see any replication. Cheers!